# Tmux copy mode - auto select whole line and trim it upon selection, copy or paste

Tags: command-line, tmux

When in copy mode I would like keyboard navigational keys to auto select whole current line. Ideally, the selected line would be trimmed upon selection/copy/paste.

**Example**

I often want to select whole, trimmed lines to select output from `git <anything>` or `ls -1` etc:

```
# git status

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        robots.txt
        index.php
        [...]
```

I want to commit robots.txt, so I enter into copy mode, and start to move the cursor towards robots.txt line. Upon moving it up, it selects first `index.php`:

```
# git status

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        robots.txt
        **index.php** (<-- text between ** is auto selected)
        [...]

# git status
```

Then upon moving cursor up (with keyboard) it selects the line with robots.txt (trimmed):

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        **robots.txt** (<-- text between ** is auto selected)
        index.php
        [...]
```

Is it something that can be done in the current version of tmux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Here's a macro that does "go up/down and select trimmed line" on `C-Up` / `C-Down` (usually Control + Up / Control + Down ):

In tmux enter command mode by `C-b :`, then use the following code:

```
bind -T copy-mode C-Up send-keys Up \; send -X back-to-indentation \; send -X begin-selection \;  send -X end-of-line 
bind -T copy-mode C-Down send-keys Down \; send -X back-to-indentation \; send -X begin-selection \;  send -X end-of-line
```

To copy the text & paste it you press `C-w` and `C-b ]`

**Gist**

Bug fixes, enhancements etc.:
https://gist.github.com/mklepaczewski/ee9c4cd85f678859c90844ef18ac8ceb

**Demo**

After `git status`:

[image]

After `C-b [` and 3x `C-Up`:

[image]

Now it's just a matter of `C-w` (to copy) followed by `C-b ]` (to paste)

Comment: As much as I don't like accepting my own answer, there are no other submissions.